# What is the resistor in this Op Amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am told that the answer is R1 = 75ohms, R2 = 65ohms and R3 = 15ohms but have no Idea why. I know that for an non-inverting amplifier, the voltage gain = (R2/R3) +1. How do we work out the values of R1, R2 and R3?

[image]

Comment: Having a load (formed by the feedback resistors) on the opamp output of 75 ohms is daft.

Comment: I agree but how are the values of the R2 and R3 resistors found?

Comment: The 75 ohm (R1) is matching the cable impedance (e.g. RG 59) but I totally agree with @Andyaka that the feedback resistors values are daft - way too low. ( *Hint: keep the same ratio to keep the same gain* )

Comment: Making R2 + R3 around 75 ohms is **pointless**, the output impedance of the circuit is the opamp's output impedance divided by the loopgain. Generally this value will be **much** lower than 75 ohm. This is **NOT** a proper design for a CATV amplifier. Whoever wrote the assignment has no clue. If you'd replace the opamp with an OTA (current output amplifier) then the output impedance is R2+R3. What matters is the **ratio** R2/R3 to set the gain. Perhaps for DC offset you'd want R1 = R2//R3

Comment: This question teaches you nothing about electronics in fact it suggests things that are plain misleading. Talk to your lecturer about this.

Comment: One of the stated requirements is that R2 + R3 = 75, so their values **cannot** be 65 and 15. Whoever told you that answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you have two equations and two unknowns.
$$75~\Omega=R_2+R_3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$ 
and
$$10~\text{dB}=1+\frac{R_2}{R_3}.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$
Using these two equations (1) and (2) you will get
$$R_3=\frac{75~\Omega}{10~\text{dB}},~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)$$
which you then can calculate. \$R_2\$ follows with eq. (1).

Comment: I had a go but it doesnt match the answers: R2 = 60Ω and R3 = 15Ω. Am  I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you divide 75 Ohm by 5 you will get R_3 = 15 Ohms (note that you have to convert the 10 dB into linear scale before using eq. (3)), which leaves R_2 to 60 Ohms. Questionable is of course the 5, which has no relation to 10 dB. I also agree that the values are not meaningful, however.

Comment: I gave it a try by converting 10db by using the: formula = 20 log Vout/Vin = 10 db. which gives 3.16. Substituting that into (3) will be R3 = 75Ω/3.16. Sorry to be a pain. Where do you get the 5 from?

Comment: I just realised. Its in the question isnt it?

Comment: The 5 is from the question you posted. It says: "[...] of 10 dB (=5). [...]". I would rather support your result of 3.16.

Comment: Blame my lecturer. He's about 90 and stronger than ever! Cheers!